# How can I do an "inline match" in F#

Tags: f#

I have a function

```
let binaryOp load store op =
    (load 0, load 1) ||> op |> store 2
```

that reads 2 values from a virtual memory, applies a binary operation on them, and writes the result back to memory. The argument's types are:

```
load: (int -> 'a)
op: ('a -> int)
store: (int -> unit)
```

As you can see `op` is restricted to return an `int`. I want to change that so `op` can return anything that can be converted to an `int`. This wouldn't be a problem usually as I could just do

```
(load 0, load 1) ||> op |> int |> store 2
```

Problem is, I want to support custom conversions too, specifically `bool` to `int` which are resolved at compile time. Something like this

```
let inline toInt (x: ^a) =
    inline match x with
    | :? bool as b -> if b then 1 else 0
    | _ -> int x

let inline binaryOp load store op =
    (load 0, load 1) ||> op |> toInt |> store 2
```

where the correct match arm is resolved at compile time and directly inlined at call site. I've chosen `inline match` for illustration purposes, but I'm fine with anything that solves my actual problem.

Is something like this possible in F#?

Comment: It's unclear how your hypothetical `inline match` is different from regular `match`. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin well my example doesn't compile with a normal match because `x` is an unrestricted generic type so I cannot do runtime coercion to `bool`.

Comment: What if you box it first?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I'd like to avoid that if possible. I'm only using primitive types so there would always be boxing going on which is kinda bad performance wise at this place. Eliding the whole type test and move that to compile time would be best.